# Serializing double to int

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a POJO like

```
public class Foo {
private double amount;

private String message;

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

When I am serializing this Foo object to JSON String using Jackson where the amount is 500 then it is coming out as 500.0. I want to get 500 instead of 500.0.

One solution is to change its type to int, however I can't modify that class.

May I know how can I do that using Jackson library?

Comment: But `500` is `500.0`.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. When you are deserializing you end up with objects of your pojo class. And those have double fields. Thus the value will end up being a double. Thus: unclear what you are asking.

Comment: There is no library to do what you're asking to do because, mostly, it doesn't make any sense. You get the object back that you serialized. Then you can do whatever you want with it, including casting values when needed.

Comment: is it possible that you just want this number being printed/displayed as "500"? Kind of a problem of how the number is being represented?

Comment: I missed mentioning it to deserialize it to JSON string.

Comment: I think the question is legitimate. The OP may want to get a more human-friendly JSON, or is constrained to use a class although he/she will always store integers in those floats and something else will read the JSON as a different class with integers, or similar situations. Not all situations are "clean".

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is because he's talking about deserializing, but it seems he's really talking about serializing to JSON.

Comment: @Kayaman you are right, I fixed that

Comment: What is the significance of having it 500 rather than 500.0, and what do you intend to do with a value that has a decimal value like 500.1? It seems more likely that the appropriate solution is to modify the value after you've deserialized it... assuming you're using it for reporting purposes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this page for a demonstration on creating custom serializers:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

A possible solution would be to create a custom serializer for the Double.class, which optionally passes an Integer to the JsonGenerator where appropriate.

I've tested this and found it to work:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    if (value.intValue() == value)
        gen.writeNumber(value.intValue());
    else
        gen.writeNumber(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have another option, which is not very clean (Honesty I would love to hear more cleaner solution than this);

```
public class FooDTO {
   private int amount;

   public int getAmount() {
     return amount;
   }

   public void setAmount(double amt) {
     amount = (int) amt;
   }
}
```

now you can serialize FooDTO after you set the amount. (please add getters and setters for your other attributes.